# Dynamic typealias Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I'm trying to set a `typealias` with a conditional like this:

```
typealias dataType = (x == y ? ButtonTableCell : InputTableCell)
```

Where both `ButtonTableCell` and `InputTableCell` are classes, so later I can use `dataType` like this:

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "buttonCell", for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! dataType
```

I don't know if this is possible in Swift

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not possible. However, you can make a protocol or generics to get close to it.

```
protocol TableCell { 
    // put stuff here
}

extension ButtonTableCell: TableCell { }
extension InputTableCell: TableCell { }

class MyClass<X: TableCell> {
    typealias dataType = X
}
```

Comment: Thank you @daniel-t